# jQuery’s .bind() vs. .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I found two great articles talking about the new function `.on()`: [jquery4u.com](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/#.UCEUoKPrFI0), [elijahmanor.com](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html).

Is there any way where the `.bind()` still is better to use than `.on()`?

For example, I have a sample code that look like this:

```
$("#container").click( function( e ) {} )
```

You can note that I just have one item retrieved by the selector and in my case, the `<div>` named `#container` already exists when my page was loaded; not added dynamically. It’s important to mention that I use the latest version of jQuery: 1.7.2.

For that sample, should `.on()` be used instead of `.bind()` even if I don’t use the other features provided by the `.on()` function?

Comment: that second article is rubbish.  It says how `.bind()` is bad for binding multiple elements, but fails to mention how `.on()` when used in binding mode does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Internally, `.bind` maps directly to `.on` in the current version of jQuery. (The same goes for `.live`.) So there is a tiny but practically insignificant performance hit if you use `.bind` instead.

However, `.bind` may be removed from future versions at any time. There is no reason to keep using `.bind` and every reason to prefer `.on` instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger They will never remove functions that were publicly exposed in their API at one point in time. There are way too many sites depending on these deprecated functions and they'd have a huge backlash if they were removed.

Comment: Probably -- there's little reason to remove them, since they just map to an existing function. On the other hand, upgrading by a major version number means you can do just about anything to the API, since backwards compatibility is not necessarily guaranteed at that point. Just sayin'.

Comment: `$.get, $.post, $.getJSON` etc all just map to `$.ajax`. It doesn't make them useless. The argument is really flawed.

Comment: @Esailija those functions all offer useful shortcuts for dealing with specific types of asynchronous requests. `.bind` and `.on` are identical for non-delegated events; `.bind` does not provide any kind of shortcut like `$.getJSON` does

Comment: @jbabey, while technically true that they don't necessarily remove any functions, they still [deprecate](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) them and advise you not to use them. In the future they could always decide to remove them entirely (kind of how they removed certain IE support as of versions 2.x). Deprecated functions should not be used.

Comment: printing "jQuery.fn.bind.toString()" outputs "function (a,b,c){return this.on(a,null,b,c)}"

Comment: bind and unbind are deprecated as of jQuery 3.

Answer (score 59):

These snippets all perform exactly the same thing:

```
element.on('click', function () { ... });
element.bind('click', function () { ... });
element.click(function () { ... });
```

However, they are very different from these, which all perform the same thing:

```
element.on('click', 'selector', function () { ... });
element.delegate('click', 'selector', function () { ... });
$('selector').live('click', function () { ... });
```

The second set of event handlers use [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) and will work for dynamically added elements. Event handlers that use delegation are also much more performant. The first set will not work for dynamically added elements, and are much worse for performance.

jQuery's `on()` function does not introduce any new functionality that did not already exist, it is just an attempt to standardize event handling in jQuery (you no longer have to decide between live, bind, or delegate).

Comment: I think you mean `$('selector').live('click', function () { ... });` so you keep the result as nearly as posible identical.

Answer (score 11):

The direct methods and `.delegate` are superior APIs to `.on` and there is no intention of deprecating them.

The direct methods are preferable because your code will be less stringly typed. You will get immediate error when you mistype an
event name rather than a silent bug. In my opinion, it's also easier to write and read `click` than `on("click"`

The `.delegate` is superior to `.on` because of the argument's order:

```
$(elem).delegate( ".selector", {
    click: function() {
    },
    mousemove: function() {
    },
    mouseup: function() {
    },
    mousedown: function() {
    }
});
```

You know right away it's delegated because, well, it says delegate. You also instantly see the selector.

With `.on` it's not immediately clear if it's even delegated and you have to look at the end for the selector:

```
$(elem).on({
    click: function() {
    },
    mousemove: function() {
    },
    mouseup: function() {
    },
    mousedown: function() {
    }
}, "selector" );
```

Now, the naming of `.bind` is really terrible and is at face value worse than `.on`. But `.delegate` cannot do non-delegated events and there 
are events that don't have a direct method, so in a rare case like this it could be used but only because you want to make a clean separation between delegated and non-delegated events.

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, *.delegate()* has been deprecated.

Comment: The direct methods all got deprecated as well. This answer didn't age well...

Answer (score 8):

If you look in the source code for `$.fn.bind` you will find that it's just an rewrite function for `on`:

```
function (types, data, fn) {
    return this.on(types, null, data, fn);
}
```

[http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=$.fn.bind](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=%24.fn.bind)

Answer (score 6):

From the jQuery documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Keep in mind, the documentation's advice is from the same team that brought you bind, click, live, delegate..., and all of the resulting confusion.  After reading multiple sites on this issue, my opinion is that the best and most accurate sites are the ones that describe 'on' as "sugar-coating", sugar attracts bugs, and delegate is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

As of Jquery 3.0 and above .bind has been deprecated and they prefer using .on instead. As @Blazemonger answered earlier that it may be removed and its for sure that it will be removed. For the older versions .bind would also call .on internally and there is no difference between them. Please also see the api for more detail.

[jQuery API documentation for .bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)