# Which jquery frunction [bind, on, live, delegate] is safe to use for event binding to guarantee compatibility with future releases?

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I came accross a few posts on stackoverflow that says `bind` will be removed from future releases of jquery and only `on` will be used for event binding. As in the following post:

[jquery .bind() vs. .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on)

Is it true that `bind` will be removed? If so which event binding function should I use?

Comment: Well, `.live` has been deprecated and `.delegate` is replaced by `.on`.

Comment: [The documentation is clear about this](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `[...]As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),  .delegate(), and .live().[...]`  [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/): `[...]As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. [...]`

Comment: I should have read read the documentation better, thank you @t.niese