# Jquery - wrapping a bind function to THIS elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple tables on a page (there will be over 100) and I want to use one function for all of them. When the user selects "Custom" in the drop-down menu, additional questions apply TO ALL OF THEM. How do I wrap my function in a THIS statement to have it only added to that individual table. I apologize in advance for my description of the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td.additional_content').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $('#srds_mapping').bind('change', function (e) { 
        if( $('#srds_mapping').val() == 'Custom') {
            $('td.additional_content').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('td.additional_content .custom').show();
        } else {
            $('td.additional_content').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('td.additional_content .custom').hide();
        }

  }).trigger('change');
});
```

It is better explained by looking at it

http://jsfiddle.net/2Q7J7/2/

Comment: use DOM traversal functions to find the related content

Comment: Hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/JS2K8/ use class selector and DOM traversal

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the targetted element inside the event handler:

```
$('#srds_mapping').bind('change', function (e) {
    if( $(this).val() == 'Custom') { // traverse to find the target input element
```

Note that you should not use more than one ID on the page. Use classes or other selectors instead, f.ex:

```
$('select').bind('change', function (e) {
    if( $(this).val() == 'Custom') {
```

Comment: @TNK It’s accepted so... anyway I won’t answer other questions than the one you asked here. If you need help with something else, just post a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery .each() function would be a good option:**

Assuming `$('#srds_mapping')` is your table. Firstly, instead of id you could add a class to the tables. For example `<table id="srds_mapping" class="srds_mapping"></table>`. After that is in place you could do something like this.

```
$('.srds_mapping').each(function(){
   $(this).bind('change', function (e) {
     // other function stuff
   }).trigger('change');
});
```

Also, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on) may be worth a read, or something to think about.