# Rationale behind $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to produce a small script using jQuery and I encountered a roadblock. My script is about turning each clicked `<tr>` object of a table into a specific style using the class `trHighlight`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('tr').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('trHighlight');
    });
});
```

I'm now trying to turn back into the *normal* style when clicking again on each row of the table (each `<tr>` object). I tried the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('tr').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).addClass('trHighlight');
    });
    $('tr .trHighlight').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).removeClass('trHighlight');
    });
});
```

A specific `if`-structure doesn't help that much too. Do you have any ideas?

Another question: Do you have a description of all properties that can be adressed through `this.x` like `this.id` - maybe I can try to find a way using the class property of "this"?

Comment: Changing the class of an element doesn't change which event handlers are bound to it.

Comment: The reason your second click handler doesn't work is because 1) there was a space in the selector (as explained by Bram below) and 2) you were adding `.trHighlight`class after the click handler has been binded. Using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) would make this work, although matthias_h's solution is the way to go. `$('table').on('click', 'tr.trHighlight', function() { $(this).removeClass('trHighlight'); });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use toggleClass():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('tr').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('trHighlight');
  });
});
```

and might consider to change `bind()` to `on()`. Both will work, for the pros and cons of both as reference: [jquery .bind() vs. .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on).
You should use `.on()` if available since `.bind()` is deprecated. But as sidenote - `bind()` is a rewrite function for `on()` - http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.0.3&fn=$.fn.bind (actualised info retrieved from this answer: [jquery .bind() vs. .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on#answer-11847101)

Comment: And it finally works! Thank you very much, as you could understand I am an absolute beginner in jQuery!

Comment: keep in mind [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used instead of .bind()

Comment: Either this, or if you really want to use separate click-handlers, use a default class: `$('tr.default').click(function(){$(this).removeClass("default").addClass('trHighlight');});`. (And vice versa for turning back to normal)

Comment: @DarkAjax Thanks for mentioning, I admit I didn't took care of the bind() as I just had the use of toggleClass() in mind. Updated answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

@matthias_h his answer is the way to go. However, for completeness sake I just want to inform you that you had a floating space that was the problem: `$('tr .trHighlight')` selects an element (no matter which) with the class `trHighlight` that is a descendant of a table row. What you wanted, though is a table row that *has* the class itself, rather than one of its descendants. Selecting a specific semantic element that has a class can be done by connecting the class and the element, like so: `$('tr.trHighlight')`. Your final script would look like the one below, however - as said - matthias_h's answer is what you should use in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').bind('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('trHighlight');
    });
    $('tr.trHighlight').bind('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('trHighlight');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some incomprehension of how JavaScript work. What's important to know is that JavaScript run once. After being run, it only listen (and run function when asked to).

So you current bind event on both `$('tr')` and `$('tr . trHighlight')` (by the way, there shouldn't be a space between the tag and the classname), but the class `trHighlight` is only added when you click on the `tr`. It isn't there when the JavaScript run so there is no event listener being attached to the element that will remove the class.

That's why there is an event delegation system. Basicaly, you attach an event on a parent static element and it will lesson to it and compare the event target to its ancestor. If the comparison match the selector, the event will successfully run the code.

I'm talking here about the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with a selector as argument. This piece of code would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('table').on('click', 'tr:not(.trHighlight)', function() {
        $(this).addClass('trHighlight');
    });
    $('table').on('click', 'tr.trHighlight', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('trHighlight');
    });
});
```

But that is not recommended in your situation. You are only changing a class and jQuery has a function for that : [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

That mean you can bind a single event on the `tr` no matter if he has or not the class. `.toggleClass`
will evaluate for you if it need to remove or add the class. This is as simple as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('tr').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('trHighlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: @AtoM_84 That's gonna be harder than I though... That concept is not so simple and I am not an native english speaker as well!

Comment: Ok so let me rephrase some of your statements just to be sure I understood it the right way (sorry, I'm not a native english speaker): 1)you mean a JS can only be based on existing objects (and their related attributes) in the DOM just after loading the document because this is when it is actually executed? Am I right? 2)That is the reason why my script is not succesfully working : a function that call the method removeClass is based on a selector for which the navigator (or anything) did not find any concerned object when executing the script (assuming the code was correctly written...)

Comment: 3) Finally you tell me that I should preferably refer to static objects for my script (so that the script would be interpreted and not consider as not useful because using not adequate selectors), and use the descendance "effect" of jQuery to succeed in doing actions of them. Is it true?

Comment: @AtoM_84 You are right on the second point. It did not work because the selector did not find anything. On your second point though, object properties (or attributes) are permanent. Once you change it, it will be changed everywhere. On your third point, I am suggesting you to use a static event. That event is binded directly to the element and not on its parent. That mean no matter of much you change your element, the event will always be bound to it and do the action (function) you tell him to do. In this case, toggling class.

Comment: @AtoM_84 here of the js work : **1) The script is insert and run.** The only thing it does is binding an event on the document waiting the dom to be ready. **2) The DOM is ready.** It run the function, The DOM is ready only once so your function run once. You function bind a click event on `tr` since it find them, but fail to find `tr.trHighlight`. So no event a bound there. **3) You click on the tr.** It add the class to the tr (it run the event). **4) You click on the same tr.** It run the same function (it is already bound) and add the class. It is already present so it does nothing.

Comment: That's great, I understand far better now some other issues I could have on an other tentative script. Thanks a lot, I keep that thread as a favorite webpage to keep all those things in mind.