# Force click on empty link to not move the page focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an empty link:

```
<a href="#" id="stop-point-btn">+ add stop-point</a>
```

bound to a JS function:

```
$("#stop-point-btn").bind("click", addStopPoint);
```

which simply adds some content in a div:

```
function addStopPoint() {
    $("#stop-point-content").append(stopPointHtml())
}
```

Upon click, if I have scrolled a bit down, it moves me back to the top of the page (of course, because of the provided `#` empty id value). But how can I make it so that the position, of where I am at the page, does not change (meaning the scroll position).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

```
 $("#stop-point-btn").bind("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addStopPoint();
    });
```

And keep in mind:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements.

Comment: So, you suggest also that I better use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` because in this case the anchor is a document, but not an element?

Comment: Not really. I meant this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on. Guess a quoted too much, which might have been confusing.

Answer (score 5):

replace the href value in javascript:void(0); and the click on the link will produce no effect

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="stop-point-btn">+ add stop-point</a>
```

Comment: This worked for me in a situation where I needed an empty parent `A` to quit shifting on click, but still allow the children to function as links.

Comment: What magic is this, thank you kind sir

Answer (score 1):

Pass event as an argument to your function and add this statement.  `event.preventDefault()` inside of addstoppoint function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `href` value is `javascript:void(0);` which return `undefined` that's why browser stays on the same page and do not scroll page.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="stop-point-btn">+ add stop-point</a>
```