# Disable event handler below a certain viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-handling

I'm currently trying to disable a script when the window width is less than 700px.
I have looked at the advice on other posts but nothing has work as of yet.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if(window.innerWidth < 700) {
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#projectinfo').hide();
            } else {
                $('#projectinfo').show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 2 nested resize handlers? There is something very wrong in that logic.

Comment: @Vohuman Where do you find the second resize handler in the OPs code example?

Comment: @connexo, I made a mistake, I should have written why binding a `scroll` handler on each `resize` event.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never **unbind** your event handler once it has been attached to the window. I suggest  you also do not bind the scroll event handler **every time** the `window.resize` event triggers, because this is an extremely costly event performance-wise. Also, you keep rebinding an already existing handler which, if it works at all, is still horribly bad practice.

What you probably really want is to decide on document.ready whether to attach the scroll handler or not. If the resize use case is really relevant (web users don't usually ever resize their browser window **while** viewing a specific page, it's just what web frontend developers keep doing to check the responsiveness of their work), first test if your scroll handler is currently attached to `window` and only add it if it is not **and** (&&) your `window.innerWidth >= 700`. Otherwise, check again if the scroll handler exist, and unbind it in case it exists **and** `window.innerWidth < 700`.

> http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Also, please note that you can name events when binding by using the `event.name` syntax when declaring the binding. Find this in the jQuery docs herefor:

> ## Using Namespaces
>
> Instead of maintaining references to handlers in order to unbind them,
>   we can namespace the events and use this capability to narrow the
>   scope of our unbinding actions. As shown in the discussion for the
>   `.bind()` method, namespaces are defined by using a period (`.`)
>   character when binding a handler:
>
> ```
> $("#foo").bind("click.myEvents", handler );
> ```
>
> When a handler is bound in this fashion, we can still unbind it the normal way:
>
> ```
> $("#foo").unbind("click");
> ```
>
> However, if we want to avoid affecting other handlers, we can be more specific:
>
> ```
> $("#foo").unbind("click.myEvent");
> ```
>
> We can also unbind all of the handlers in a namespace, regardless of event type:
>
> ```
> $("#foo").unbind(".myEvent");
> ```
>
> It is particularly useful to attach namespaces to event bindings when we are developing plug-ins or
>   otherwise writing code that may interact with other event-handling
>   code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`unbind` and `bind` perhaps

```
var $w = $(window);

function scrollHandler(e) {
  $('#projectinfo').toggle($w.scrollTop() > 100);
}

$(window).resize(function (e) {
  $w.width() < 700 ? $w.bind('scroll', scrollHandler) : $w.unbind('scroll', scrollHandler);
});
```

Obviously this needs some optimization improvements, but it's just to show the basic idea.

Comment: Even though I recognize your intention to help, advising re/un-binding the same handlers over and over again is probably not the best way to "show the basic idea". As a small side note, there is no need to pass the event explicitly if you don't ever need to access it inside your handler function, so it's probably better in this case to leave it out. Also, it definitely doesn't help beginners understand your code suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use bind** (it is deprecated), use **on** (and **off**). Some other suggestions in comments

```
(function ($, w, d) {
    $(function () {
        var $projectinfo = $('#projectinfo');
        var $w = $(w);
        var useScroll;

        function useScroll() {
            if ($w.scrollTop() > 100) {
                // Don't use hide() and show(), add or remove a class, instead
                $projectinfo.addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $projectinfo.removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        function checkWindowWidth() {
            var useScrollTop = $w.width() < 700;
            if (useScrollTop) { 
                $w.on('scroll', useScroll);
            } else {
                $w.off('scroll', useScroll);
            }
        };

        // On resize, just check once the viewport width
        $w.on('resize', function () {
            // You should use a 'debounce' function, for this
            checkWindowWidth();
        });


    })
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

See this: [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), [bind vs on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on)