# video.onended firing only once?

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm using a onended to trigger something, but it seems to fire only once. That is to say, when I play the video and it ends, it fires, but if I play the video a second time (including after page refresh) it doesn't fire again.

Any clues?

```
$('video').bind('ended', function() {
    alert('ended!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **on** function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('video').on('ended',function(){
   console.log('Video has ended!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Internally, `.bind` maps directly to `.on` in the jQuery 2.1.3.

Comment: i thought bind has been depreciated but in current version still using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on

Answer (score 0):

It should works, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ujd595fz/2) fiddle.

- Make sure that you don't call `removeEventListener` or `jQuery.unbind` somewhere in your code.
- Make sure that you don't have any errors, check your browser's debug console.