# JQuery Values are not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Search", "GetDateWiseGuestReport", "Reports", new { StartDate = "sss",EndDate="eee" }, new { @id = "btnDateWiseGuestSearch",  @class = "btn btn-red" })


$("#btnDateWiseGuestSearch").bind('click', function () {
                //Get the id of the selected item in dropdown

            var EndDate = $("#txtDateWiseGuestEndDate").val();
            var StartDate = $("#txtDateWiseGuestStartDate").val();

              this.href = this.href.replace("sss", StartDate);
              this.href = this.href.replace("eee", EndDate);
 });
```

Okay i am using above code to change the Action-link URL at run time.Everything is running smoothly. but i have a strange issue i.e. when i click the button 1st time its gets the values from text boxes and change accordingly, but when i press button again its doesn't get new values from text boxes rather its somehow using OLD VALUES that i inputted 1st time!

Comment: Consider using the `.on('click')` function instead of bind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because after the firs click you are replacing the `sss` and `eee` from the href so there after is no `sss` or `eee` in the href. So nothing is replaced after the first click

So a possible solution is to store the original href value somewhere else then use that for replacing the content. In the below solution the data api is used to store the original value

```
var $btn = $("#btnDateWiseGuestSearch");
$btn.data('href', $btn.attr('href'))
$btn.bind('click', function () {
    //Get the id of the selected item in dropdown

    var EndDate = $("#txtDateWiseGuestEndDate").val();
    var StartDate = $("#txtDateWiseGuestStartDate").val();

    var href = $(this).data('href');
    this.href = href.replace("sss", StartDate).replace("eee", EndDate);
});
```

Comment: Okay i got it! but how am i suppose to store "sss" , "eee"??

Comment: Sorry.. what do you mean by `store "sss" , "eee"`

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your jQuery code you are create a new link by replacing `sss` and `eee` however once you have replaced them that is it, you won't find them again

```
this.href = this.href.replace("sss", StartDate); // sss no longer exists after this
this.href = this.href.replace("eee", EndDate); // sss no longer exists after this
```

What you will need to do is store the original href value before you modify it and then reference that when you want to update the link

```
$("#btnDateWiseGuestSearch").bind('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var originalhref = $this.data("href");
    if(!originalhref){
        this.data("href", this.href);
    }

    var EndDate = $("#txtDateWiseGuestEndDate").val();
    var StartDate = $("#txtDateWiseGuestStartDate").val();

    this.href = originalhref.replace("sss", StartDate).replace("eee", EndDate);
 });
```