# what is the difference between bind and on function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I had been asked this question in two of my interviews I know what is what, I know bind has been deprecated in JQuery 1.7 and above and on function is used for bind , delegate and live and also that in current implementation bind uses on only 
  But is there any specific difference between the two ? Trust me I have searched the online but nothing is very convincing differences hat I could find.

Comment: Looks like no difference at all. http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.bind

Answer (score 0):

`bind` is the old syntax. `on` and `off` were created to unify how event handlers are defined. [A previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on) gives a bit more detail.