# Unbind previous events jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'ts possible to unbind  the previos events of a button ,something like that

```
$("#my-button").on('click',function(){
        $( "#my-button" ).unbind();
        alert('whatever');
      });
```

Comment: Use `one` to bind event which will automatically unbind once it is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind click using [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$( "#my-button" ).unbind( "click" );
```

Comment: I believe it's off()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#my-button").off('click').on('click',function() {
  alert('whatever');
});
```

Documentation for [jQuery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

Comment: I was finding it strange too so I upvoted you, but I found that your answer says `off('click').on('click')` so my guess is the answer itself is ambiguous

Comment: That's is how I do it. except I use `unbind().bind('...',function(){})` is the `off().on()` way preferable to the `unbind().bind()` method?

Comment: Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11847066/2968762) answer for difference for **bind** and **on**. Secondly, **off** will remove the previously attached event handler and **on** will rebind it, that is the whole concept behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#my-button" ).unbind("click");
```

click can be any event we want to unbind.

unbind need to know which event it has to unbind.

Answer (score 0):

TO unbind event used:

```
$("#my-button").off('click');
```