# show div after scrolling in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, media-queries

i want show a div after scrolling 150px just in mobile devices.
this is my code but it doesnt work :

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", checkPosition));
var phonebox = $(".phonebox");
function checkPosition()
{
    if($(window).width() < 460)
    {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
       phonebox.show();
      }
    else {
       phonebox.hide();
    }
});  
    } 
}
```

can somebody help me to fix this problem.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `bind` but `on` instead. And use both `resize` and `load` in the same function.

`bind` is an *old* version of new added `on` see here > [bind vs on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on)

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c98axo1h/)

or snippet below ( i used 700 for example purposes only. so it works in snippet )

```js
$(window).on("load resize", checkPosition)
var phonebox = $(".phonebox");

function checkPosition() {
  if ($(window).width() < 700) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $(phonebox).show();
      } else {
        $(phonebox).hide();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.phonebox {
 top:200px;
 height:300px;
 width:100px;
 position:absolute;
 background:red;
 display:none;
}
.for_scroll {
 height:1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phonebox">

</div>
<div class="for_scroll">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one,

```
$(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scroll >= 150){
            phonebox.show();
        }else{
            phonebox.hide();
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this one as show() and hide() functions are not supported by some of the browsers so this could be a reason.

```
To hide:
$(".phonebox").css("display", "none");

To show:
$(".phonebox").css("display", "block");
```