# If I enable paste, then validation is not being done

Tags: javascript

I tried this but I am not able to apply validation on paste:

```
    function blockSpecialCharacter(event) {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
     $('#businessId').bind('keypress ', function(e) {
                     blockSpecialCharacter(e);
               });
```

Do tell me how to enable paste with above validation?

Comment: Well you could decide that you can copy and paste using the letters c and v.  Otherwise you'd need to allow those particular key presses to pass through..

Comment: You can apply validation on `blur` event as well, which will handle `copy-paste` case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons why your code is not working :

- Pasting with Ctrl+V doesn't trigger the `keypress` event
- If it did, you would not be able to retrieve pasted data with `event.charCode`

So, I suggest you use a different event handler, listening to the `paste` event and retrieving data via `event.originalEvent.clipBoardData`

Here is a working example that blocks the pasted data in case it contains at least one special character.

```js
  
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
  function blockSpecialCharacter(event) {
     
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
   console.log(key);
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
  }
  
  function blockPaste(event) {
   var pastedData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
   
   if (!regex.test(pastedData)) {
   console.warn("Pasted data contains some non allowed character");
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
  }
  
 $('#businessId').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  blockSpecialCharacter(e);
 });
 
  $('#businessId').bind('paste', function(e) {
  blockPaste(e);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Paste data here : <br/>
<input type="text" name="businessId" id="businessId" value=""/>
<br/><br/>
Text ready to be copied : <br/>
<textarea rows="3" cols="40">
lorem
loreµ</textarea>
```

`

Comment: Preference for `.on(` vs `.bind(` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847066/125981