# Should I use bind() or on() with DOMSubtreeModified

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `DOMSubtreeModified` event is working well in both the below cases, but I don't know which one is best to use.

```
$('#mydiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
 alert('changed');
});
```

or

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#mydiv", function() {
 alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-s-bind-vs-on

Comment: For all versions of jQuery higher than 1.7 you should be using `on()`.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan & Aswin Kumar